# CSS position sticky not working with dynamic table

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc

I try to set position sticky for the below table with no luck
the below table is inside parents dev I try to give it Height and remove `overflow:hidden` or change it to `overflow:auto` also with no luck

```
div id="app" class="jsgrid" style="position: relative;  width: 100%; padding:10px;">
    <div class="action-bnts" v-if="Exports == false">
        <button :disabled="TotalcountUndo === 0 || EnableUndoRedo === false" style="margin-bottom:10px;" v-on:click="undofunc()" type="button" id="Undobtn" class="btn btn-secondary btn-ft">Undo</button>
        <button :disabled="TotalcountRedo === 0 || EnableUndoRedo === false" style="margin-bottom:10px;" v-on:click="Redofunc()" type="button" id="Redo" class="btn btn-secondary btn-ft">Redo</button>
        <button style="margin-bottom:10px;" v-on:click="exports" type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-ft">Exports and preview</button>
    </div>

    

    <div class="main-grid" >
        <div class="jsgrid-grid-header jsgrid-header-scrollbar" style=" overflow-y: hidden !important;">

            <table class="jsgrid-table">
                <tr class="jsgrid-header-row" ref="myColid" :disabled="EnableUndoRedo === false">

                    <th v-for="(colo, coindex) in ColumnTemp" :class='"jsgrid-header-cell jsgrid-header-sortable filtered" + coindex' width="150px" v-show="coindex != 0 && coindex != 2" :key="colo" v-bind:style="{backgroundColor:colo.Color}" :colspan="colo.collapan">
                        <div style="float: left;display:none" :class="'coindex'+ coindex" v-if="coindex != 1">
                            <input class="jsgrid-button jsgrid-cancel-edit-button" type="button" title="Close Editor" v-on:click="bluretext('coindex'+ coindex)" />
                            <input type="color" :id="'Color'+ coindex" />
                            <input class="btn btn-secondary btn-ft" type="button" :id="'colorButton'+ coindex" value="change Color" v-on:click="changeColorColumn('Color'+ coindex , coindex   )" />

                            <textarea type="text" v-model="ColumnTemp[coindex].Name"
                                      placeholder="Default" :name="'columnindex'+ coindex"></textarea>

                        </div>

                        <div class="row" v-if="coindex != 1">
                            <div :id="'coindex' + coindex">
                                <p v-on:click='SwapText("coindex" + coindex , coindex)' v-html="ColumnTemp[coindex].Name" style="font-size:24px;color:black;font-family:Arial"></p>
                                <input style="margin:0" class="jsgrid-button jsgrid-cancel-edit-button" type="button" title="Delete Column" v-on:click="deleteCol(coindex, colo)" />
                                <input style="margin:0" class="jsgrid-button jsgrid-mode-button jsgrid-insert-mode-button" type="button" title="Add Substage" v-on:click="AddSubstage(coindex, colo)" />

                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <p v-if="coindex ===1">Description</p>

                    </th>



                    <th class="jsgrid-header-cell jsgrid-control-field jsgrid-align-center col" style="width:150px;">
                        

                        <span class="jsgrid-header-span">
                            Add Stage
                        </span>

                        <button :disabled="EnableUndoRedo === false" type='button' class="jsgrid-button jsgrid-mode-button jsgrid-insert-mode-button" v-on:click="addNewCol">
                        </button>
                    </th>
                </tr>
                <tr class="jsgrid-row" ref="myTitid">
                    <td v-for="(Tit, TIndex) in Titles" :class='"jsgrid-cell col filTitle" + TIndex' style="width:150px;" v-show="TIndex != 0 && TIndex != 2" :key="Tit" v-bind:style="{backgroundColor:Tit.Color}">
                        <div :class="'keyyTitle'+ TIndex" style="display:none">
                            <input class="jsgrid-button jsgrid-cancel-edit-button" type="button" title="Close Editor" v-on:click="bluretextTitle('keyyTitle'+ TIndex)" />

                            <input type="color" :id="'ColorTitle'+ TIndex" />
                            <input class="btn btn-secondary btn-ft" type="button" :id="'colorTitleButton'+ TIndex" value="change Color" v-on:click="changeColorTitle('ColorTitle'+ TIndex , TIndex)" />

                            <input v-if="TIndex != 1" v-on:focus='AddTitlesHistory(Titles)' v-on:change='AddTitlesundoHistory()' type="text" v-model="Titles[TIndex].Name" value="Title" />
                        </div>
                        <div :id="'keyyTitle'+ TIndex">
                            <p v-if="TIndex != 1 " value="Default" v-on:click="SwapTextTitle('keyyTitle'+ TIndex)">{{Titles[TIndex].Name}}</p>
                        </div>
                        <div :id="'keyyTitle'+ TIndex">
                            <input v-if="((ColSpan[TIndex] != '' && ColSpan[TIndex] > 1) || (ParentSpan[TIndex] !='') ) && TIndex != 1" style="margin:0" class="jsgrid-button jsgrid-cancel-edit-button" type="button" title="Delete SubStage" v-on:click="deleteSubStage(Tit , TIndex)" />
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tbody ref="myid" :disabled="EnableUndoRedo === false">
                    <tr class="jsgrid-alt-row" v-for="(invoice_product, k) in Rows" :key="invoice_product">
                        <td class="jsgrid-cell" style="width: 300px;" v-for="(column, indexColumn) in columns" :key="indexColumn" v-show="indexColumn !=0 && indexColumn !=2 " v-bind:style="{backgroundColor:invoice_product[2]}">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div style="display:none" :class="'keyy'+ k +indexColumn">
                                    <input class="jsgrid-button jsgrid-cancel-edit-button" type="button" title="Close Editor" v-on:click="bluretextrow('keyy'+ k +indexColumn)" v-if="indexColumn == 1" />

                                    <div class="row" v-if="indexColumn == 1">

                                        <input type="color" :id="'Color'+ k +indexColumn" />
                                        <input class="btn btn-secondary btn-ft" type="button" value="change Row Color" v-on:click="changeRowColor('Color'+ k +indexColumn , k  )" />

                                    </div>
                                    <textarea type="text" v-model="invoice_product[indexColumn]"
                                              placeholder="Default" :name="'key'+ k +indexColumn" v-if="indexColumn == 1"></textarea>
                                </div>
                                <p v-html="invoice_product[indexColumn]" v-if="indexColumn == 1 && invoice_product[indexColumn] != ''" value="Default" :id="'keyy'+ k +indexColumn" v-on:click="SwapTextRow('keyy'+ k +indexColumn , k ,indexColumn)"></p>

                                <p v-if="indexColumn == 1 && invoice_product[indexColumn] == ''" :id="'keyy'+ k +indexColumn" v-on:click="SwapTextRow('keyy'+ k +indexColumn , k ,indexColumn )">Default Description</p>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group" v-if="indexColumn != 1">
                                <div style="display:none" :class="'keyy'+ k +indexColumn">
                                    <input class="jsgrid-button jsgrid-cancel-edit-button" type="button" title="Close Editor" v-on:click="bluretextrow('keyy'+ k +indexColumn)" />

                                    <input type="file" name="fileinput + k +indexColumn" style="width:100%" v-on:change="uploadFile($event , k , indexColumn , 'key'+ k +indexColumn)" ref="file" :maxFileSize="1000000" />

                                    <button style="margin-bottom:10px;" v-on:click="AddNote('key'+ k +indexColumn)" type="button" id="Undobtn" class="btn btn-secondary btn-ft">Add Note</button>


                                    <textarea type="text" v-model="invoice_product[indexColumn]"
                                              placeholder="Default" :name="'key'+ k +indexColumn"></textarea>
                                </div>
                                <p v-html="invoice_product[indexColumn]" v-if="indexColumn != 1 && invoice_product[indexColumn] != ''" value="Default" :id="'keyy'+ k +indexColumn" v-on:click="SwapTextRow('keyy'+ k +indexColumn , k ,indexColumn)"></p>
                                <p v-if="indexColumn != 1 && invoice_product[indexColumn] == ''" :id="'keyy'+ k +indexColumn" v-on:click="SwapTextRow('keyy'+ k +indexColumn , k ,indexColumn )">Default Description</p>


                            </div>

                        </td>
                        <td class="jsgrid-cell jsgrid-control-field jsgrid-align-center" style="width: 50px;">
                            <input :disabled="EnableUndoRedo === false" class="jsgrid-button jsgrid-cancel-edit-button" type="button" title="Delete Row" v-on:click="deleteRow(k, invoice_product)">
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
                <tr class="jsgrid-alt-row" v-show="SemanticFlage === true">
                    <td class="jsgrid-cell" style="width:300px;" v-for="(column, indexColumn) in Semantics" :key="indexColumn" v-show="indexColumn !=0 && indexColumn !=2 && indexColumn == 1">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div style="display:none" :class="'Sema' +indexColumn">
                                <textarea type="text" v-model="Semantics[indexColumn].Name"
                                          placeholder="Default" :name="'Semantic' + indexColumn" :id="'Semantic' + indexColumn" v-if="indexColumn == 1"></textarea>
                            </div>
                            <p v-html="Semantics[indexColumn].Name" style="font-size:50px" v-if="indexColumn == 1 && Semantics[indexColumn].Name != ''" value="Default" :id="'Sema' +indexColumn" v-on:click="SwapTextSemantic('Sema' +indexColumn ,indexColumn)"></p>

                            <p v-if="indexColumn == 1 && Semantics[indexColumn].Name == ''" :id="'Sema' +indexColumn" v-on:click="SwapTextSemantic('Sema' +indexColumn ,indexColumn)">Default Description</p>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="jsgrid-cell" style="width: 300px;" v-for="(column, indexColumn) in Semantics" v-show="indexColumn !=0 && indexColumn !=2 && indexColumn != 1" >

                        <div class="form-group" v-if="indexColumn > 1">
                            <div style="display:none" :class="'Sema' +indexColumn">
                                <textarea type="text" v-model="Semantics[indexColumn].Name"
                                          placeholder="Default" :name="'Semantic' + indexColumn" :id="'Semantic' + indexColumn"></textarea>
                            </div>
                            <p v-html="Semantics[indexColumn].Name" style="font-size:50px" v-if="indexColumn > 1 && Semantics[indexColumn].Name != ''" value="Default" :id="'Sema' +indexColumn" v-on:click="SwapTextSemantic('Sema' +indexColumn ,indexColumn)"></p>

                            <p v-if="indexColumn > 1 && Semantics[indexColumn].Name == ''" :id="'Sema' +indexColumn" v-on:click="SwapTextSemantic('Sema' +indexColumn ,indexColumn)">Default Description</p>

                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="jsgrid-cell jsgrid-control-field jsgrid-align-center"></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>





 body {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 2rem;
    }

    table {
        text-align: left;
        position: relative;
        border-collapse: collapse;
    }

    th, td {
        padding: 0.25rem;
    }

    th {
        position: sticky;
        top: 0; /* Don't forget this, required for the stickiness */
    }
```

I know that code is very complicated but it work dynamicity by backend developers. When I try to make simple table from zero using only CSS and html position sticky worked I don't know where is the problem